Reading an Excel file in GCS bucket using IICS CDI
So, the ask is to read an excel file from a GCS bucket and create a csv out of it. I have created a structure parser for this.
Now, in CDI, I have created a mapping.

The source connection is a google could storage v2.
in the source bucket, I have a flat file (x.txt) that has the link to the actual source excel file. The data is in the following format:

"filepath"
"gs://<bucket_name>/<file_name.xlsx>"


After the source, sits the structure parser. It has two inputs, the file path and the data. I am using the x.txt file to pass the gcs bucket path to the structure parser.

One of the groups from the structure parser is passed on to the target.


When I execute this map, I get the error, that the actual source excel file - "file_name.xlsx" can not be read.
The exact error message is as follows: "[ERROR] Cannot find the input file. For a flat file source transformation, verify that you used a reference file. Verify that all referenced file paths are valid. The following file was not found: [File name: gs://<bucket_name>/<file_name>.xlsx]"
Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Can you edit the question to add an excerpt of the source file that opens the XL file to parse it? Text is best pasted into the question in a text block delimited by triple-back-ticks.

HI, I have edited the original comment to show how the source file looks. Hope this helps.
